# std::vector push_back class from a different namespace

Tags: c++

I have a little example.

Im trying to add data to my std::vector from a class that is not in the same namespace.

both classes are the same.

How can i push data to to vector from a class that is not in same namespace

```
class A
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int32_t Size;
};

namespace TEST {

    class A
    {
    public:
        std::string name;
        int32_t Size;
    };

    class File
    {
    public:
        std::vector<A> data;

    };
}

int main()
{
    A data = { "outside namespace", 10 };

    TEST::File file;
    file.data.push_back(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "both classes are the same." no they are not. `A` is a different class than `TEST::A`

Comment: ok so how to i convert one to the other?

Comment: The same way you convert any class to any other one.

Comment: btw this sounds very much like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: well i want to copy the class, i thought i could do it with a operator?

Comment: Why do you need identical classes in different namespaces?

Comment: ^^ this and why do you want to use a `std::vector<TEST::A>` when you actually need a `std::vector<A>` ?

Comment: Because i was trying to show a example. i have 2 base classes one has a single `A` object, the other has a vector for it, i need to copy from the class that is not in the namespace to the other one.

Comment: sounds like in your real code there is only one `A` not two ?

Comment: `i need to copy from the class that is not in the namespace to the other one` Then do not define A inside TEST

Comment: is it perhaps that you dont know how to declare (inside the namespace) a vector<A> without declaring a new A (inside that namespace) ? Try `::A` to refer to the `A` in the global namespace

Comment: I know how to declear no needto be rude, thought i was asking a simple questions.

Comment: noone is rude here, we are just trying to help you

Comment: `std::vector<A> data;` refers to the A class outside of TEST unless you put another A class inside TEST, then it will refer to the local one. There 2 solutions, don't put A inside TEST or explicitly indicate that you want to use vector with the global A  `std::vector<::A> data;`

Comment: how cani copy A to TEST:A to use in my vector?

Comment: the same how you copy an instance of any other class `A` to an instance of class `B`. You need to write some code for it, there are several ways to do that. One would be to define conversion operators

Comment: `how cani copy A to TEST:A to use in my vector?` you have to convert `A` to `TEST::A` then you can copy it

Comment: @user463035818 i have tried with `A& operator=(::A&)` if thats what you mean but i cant use it in push back

Comment: what do you mean "you cant use it" ? I would suggest you to open another question where you show the problematic code with the error message, as it seems to be quite different from the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need an extra constructor in `TEST::A` for copying members from global `A`:

```
namespace TEST {

    class A
    {
    public:
        A(const ::A& a) :
            name(a.name),
            Size(a.Size)
        {}

        std::string name;
        int32_t Size;
    };
...
```

When pushing to vector do it like this:

```
int main()
{
    A data = { "outside namespace", 10 };

    TEST::File file;
    file.data.push_back(TEST::A(data));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i push data to to vector from a class that is not in same
>   namespace

The problem isnt really different namespaces, but the problem is that `A` and `TEST::A` are two different classes and you cannot push an `A` into a vector of `TEST::A`s.

Answer (score 1):

Just qualify the names with the namespace name:

```
TEST::A data = { "outside namespace", 10 };
```

`A` and `TEST::A` are two different classes.

Comment: `A data` was a example i have datta from one class i need to copy to the other so i can use pushback

Answer (score 0):

You declare your vector to accept objects from the relevant class in its namespace:

```
std::vector<A> v; // will accept objects of class A

std::vector<TEST::A> v; // will accept objects of class TEST::A
```